# momentjs display at least one day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When using

```
<script> moment().format();document.write(moment('" . $date . "', 'DD/MM/YYYY').fromNow());</script>
```

to show fuzzy dates in my task management website, how can I make momentJS only display how many days until $date? Right now, it will say something like "9 hours" when it should say "tomorrow" or similar. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use [`calendar`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) instead of [`fromNow`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

See `moment().calendar(referenceTime, formats);` [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) to see how to customize output.

Here a working sample:

```js
//moment().format();
document.write(
  moment('29/10/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY').calendar(null, {
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. That was exactly what I needed.